# How do you catch with a pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-lettable-operators

How do I do the following with lettable operators and pipe?

```js
    this.httpClient
      .get(url)
      .map((res: any) => {
        const events = res.eventList;
        return events.map(e => new EventLogModel(e));
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

I've tried this, but I can't get `catchError` to work: `catchError does not exist on type Observable<any>`:

```js
    this.httpClient
      .get(url)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          const events = res.eventList;
          return events.map(e => new EventLogModel(e));
        })
      )
      .catchError(this.handleError);
```

Also, I assume `catch` and `catchError` are the same, correct? I'm importing it like so:

`import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';`

but I wasn't sure if this was the correct operator to use.

Comment: Did you check the docs? `catchError` should be inside the pipe and should not have a dot `.` https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#error-handling

Comment: Apparently not. So that means you'd do `.pipe(map((res: any) => {}), catchError(this.handleError));`?

Comment: That looks about right :)

Comment: FYI `catchError(this.handleError))` is a bug waiting to happen. The Angular docs should not be blindly followed.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, the lettable operator `catchError` is the same as `catch`.

As for the placement of `catchError`, it should not have prefix `.` and should be placed within `pipe`:

```
this.httpClient
  .get(url)
  .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      const events = res.eventList;
      return events.map(e => new EventLogModel(e));
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError);
  )
```

Comment: For future readers, here is a crappy no frills handleError routine.

Comment: //import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
          //alert('ErrorEvent ' + error.error.message);
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
          // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
          // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,

Comment: //alert('Else ' + error.status + ':::' + error.error);
          console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an observable with a user-facing error message
        return throwError(
          'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
      };

Comment: How do I import catchError ?

Comment: @DipenduPaul import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';